# Is this a result of overproofing (dense bottom, springy top)

Tags: bread

I make the *pain de campagne* recipe from [Reinhart's *Apprentice* book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/39910.The_Bread_Baker_s_Apprentice) weekly. It's a lovely recipe and we love the bread. However, during final proofing and shaping I do battle with very large bubbles in the dough. Also, sometimes the finished loaves are dense on the bottom (see the pic below). Is the dense bottom a result of overproofing? Are the big bubbles a result of me using active dry yeast instead of the instant yeast specified in the recipe?

As I said, the bread is lovely and delicious, but I think I can do better.

[image]

Comment: is it a typo, or does the author refers to it as "pane de campagne"?

Comment: Honestly that crumb looks nearly ideal. If you want a more regular crumb, bake it in zero gravity.

Comment: @Sneftel Hmm. Alright then. I will continue doing what I'm doing.